# TLS mapping for syslog

Tags: c#, ssl, syslog

Anyone used `TLS` mapping for `Syslog`?
Before I read the whole RFC-[5424](http://www.rfc-editor.org/pdfrfc/rfc5424.txt.pdf) i wanted to ask here if there is someone with any kind of experience and maybe an advance how to use it. I wanted to implement a client in c# if there is any suggestion please let me know.